# Overflow Scroll Not Scrolling?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

Not sure if there is an issue with nested DIV that prevents scrolling or I have missed something in the code itself. At any rate cant seem to get the div with class .txtpodscroll to actually scroll. Bar appears fine just wont scroll? Below is the CSS rule I have applied to the DIV

```
.txtpodscroll {
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 20px;
width: 360px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
height: 300px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
position: fixed;
```

}

```
            <div class="holder-northeastphotobooth">
              <div class="imgpod"><img src="alt-img/nephotobooth-logo.png" width="370" height="89"></div>
              <div class="txtpodscroll">Photo booths are one of the most sought-after wedding reception additions, and we’ve got one of the best ready to bring to your big day.   We will deliver our professional booth to your venue, assemble it, and man it for the duration to make sure your guests have a great time taking lots of memorable pictures. Afterwards, we’ll dismantle and clear away the booth.   We can be as formal or as crazy as you like and will tailor it to suit your needs. You can select a range of fun green screen backgrounds for guests to choose from, allow uploading to Facebook, add multiple pictures to each print, take videos, and we can even bring along a box full of fun props for your guests to wear.   Hire our booth and you’ll get unlimited pictures and prints on the night, plus we’ll give you a USB stick with all of the pictures on to take away and for a limited time we’ll even supply a 2nd set of prints in a lovely photo album for you to take home and treasure. </div>
            </div>
```

Plus this is a link to it live and not working.

http://www.yourwedding.com/yourweddingwow/index-northeastphotobooth.html

Comment: copied and paste you css html and it seems to be scrolling ..[http://jsfiddle.net/fPLP2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a div with a class of `.wowbook-gutter-shadow` that you have placed on top of the scroll bar, this is why it doesn't scroll

if you give `.txtpodscroll` the following style: `z-index:2` it should fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

it's because the book's inner shadow is above the scrollbar, so you cannot click it, but you still see it because the shadow is a transparent PNG...
change this line:

**standard-variable.css (line 83)**

```
.holder-northeastphotobooth {
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    height: 470px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;  /* added */
    width: 370px;
    z-index: 1;   /* added */
}
```

Make sure to **remove** the background property as well, so the shadow will be shown **"under"** the page, and not above it. try it on firebug and see, it's very easy to fix.

Answer (score -2):

To prevent scroll you should use "percentage".

```
.txtpodscroll {
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 20px;
width: 360%;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
height: 300px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
position: fixed;
}
```

if the scroll is horizontal.

```
width: 360%;
```

Hope this helps.